# self.navigationController is not null but pushViewController is not working

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.5, pushviewcontroller

Basically, I have the following two methods that pushes the same call view controller _vcCall. pushViewController is working fine under on_calling method, but is not working under on_incoming_call. I am sure that self.navigationController is not null and _vcCall is not null neither. I had printed out both navigationController and _vcCall in both methods and they all have the same address. I even tried to create a new viewcontroller in on_incoming_call, but it's still not working.

I have only one button in the screen and it pushes to the call view controller when it is clicked. when on_calling method is triggered it pushes to _vcCall successfully, but when on_incoming_call is triggered it does nothing but blocks me from clicking on the Call button. it seems like there is a transparent page being pushed on current view controller.

[image]

Can someone help, please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   _vcCall = [[CallViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void) sipConnection: (SIPConnection *) connection on_calling: (NSDictionary *) userInfo     {
   NSLog(@"on_calling: navi: %@", self.navigationController);
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:_vcCall animated:YES];
}

- (void)sipConnection:(SIPConnection *)connection on_incoming_call:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   NSLog(@"on_incoming_call: navi: %@", self.navigationController);
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:_vcCall animated:YES];
}
```

This is the output in console when on_calling is triggered first

```
on_calling: navi: <navViewController: 0x77779d0>
on_incoming_call: navi: <navViewController: 0x77779d0>
```

The following part is where the delegate methods are called

```
- (void) processCallMediaState: (NSDictionary *) userInfo {
   int state = [[userInfo objectForKey: kState] intValue];
   switch(state) {
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_CALLING: { // After INVITE is sent.
         [self.delegate sipConnection:self on_calling:userInfo];
         break;
      }
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_INCOMING: {// After INVITE is received.
         [self.delegate sipConnection:self on_incoming_call:userInfo];
         break;
      }
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY: {// After response with To tag.
         break;
      }
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING:{ // After 2xx is sent/received.
         break;
      }
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED: { // After ACK is sent/received.
         [self.delegate sipConnection:self on_respond:userInfo];
         break;
      }
      case PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED: {
         [self.delegate sipConnection:self on_ending:userInfo];
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what it does say on calling of on_incoming_call???
I mean does it give any error message or something in console?

Comment: from where u calling these two methods?

Comment: I just updated my post and added a screenshot. It doesn't show any error messages. it just does nothing. these two methods are delegate methods called by a sip connection class. and I am 200% sure that they are triggered, since I am seeing those messages in the methods.

Comment: What is calling these methods ? do you have more code we can use, it must be something else, I see no problem with this code.

Comment: I can't think of any relevant part. these call methods are delegate methods from SIPConnection. It doesn't make sense to me that pushviewcontroller works in one method but doesn't work in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code isn't being called on a background thread as anything to do with UI must be run on the main thread.

I am not sure but calling push on the same instance of the view controller may be the culprit. Try setting up a new instance each time you push rather than :) doing it in the ViewDidLoad Method.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally get it work when I perform the pushviewcontroller on main thread. it looks like on_incoming_call is called by different thread

Comment: A handy way of ensuring a particular method is called on the main thread is to include:  NSAssert([NSThread mainThread],@"Not on the main thread!");